# How to create a comment box with time and date stamp in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

There's a template in Access 2010 called Contacts. On the form there's a comment box, a text box below it and a button. When you enter text into the text box and click the button it adds the text to the comment box and time/date stamps it. If you do it again it preserves the old text in the comment box and adds the new text below it.

I'm pretty new to access, but I would like to be able to add this feature to my database.

So I've got a Memo field on the table and form and an input text box and button on the form. Does anyone know what I do from here to get that functionality?

Comment: Do you know how to write any VBA code? What have you tried so far? Did you look at the code in the Contacts Template to see how they do it?

Comment: When the database template is open, on the left navigation window there is tables, queries, forms and reports. I don't see any macros, or would they be somewhere else? When I click on VB editor at the top there is no code. And when I click Run macro, there are no macros in the drop down menu.

Comment: Just found out it's a web template, which may be the reason. I didn't know I had to use VBA code, any idea what I'd have to do to get that functionality? I'm a bit of a newbie with this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example of how to do it.  I have the following form:

[image]

With the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdAppendComment_Click()
  If (IsNull(txtNewComment.value)) Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter a comment before clicking" & _
            "on the Append Comment button.")
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If (IsNull(txtComment.value)) Then
    txtComment.value = txtNewComment.value & " ~ " & _
               VBA.DateTime.Date & " ~ " & VBA.DateTime.Time
  Else
    txtComment.value = txtComment.value & _
               vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               txtNewComment.value & " ~ " & _
               VBA.DateTime.Date & " ~ " & VBA.DateTime.Time
  End If

  txtNewComment.value = ""
End Sub
```

What this does is verify that the New Comment has something in it.  If so, then it checks the Comment to see if it already contains something.  If it does, then it appends the new comment to it, else it just assigns the new comment to it.  The date and time is added to the end of each comment.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out I had to use the On_Click property of the button and add VBA code to it.

```
Private Sub cmdAddNote_Click()
 Dim MyDate As String

 MyDate = Now()


 Form_ClientF.txtNotes = vbCrLf + MyDate + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Form_ClientF.txtAddNote + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Form_ClientF.txtNotes

 Form_ClientF.txtAddNote = ""

End Sub
```