# String only added to textbox when textbox already has text in it

Tags: ms-access, vba

The user enters text into txtAddNote then clicks the cmdAddNote button, the VBA runs and appends the note to txtNotes with a time and date stamp.

But it works only when there's already text in txtNotes. What do I have to do to make it work when txtNotes is empty?

```
Private Sub cmdAddNote_Click()
 Dim MyDate As String

 MyDate = Now()

 Form_ClientF.txtNotes = vbCrLf + MyDate + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Form_ClientF.txtAddNote + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Form_ClientF.txtNotes

 Form_ClientF.txtAddNote = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: See my  [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19163157/1253219) on your previous question for how to accomplish this.  It checks the Comment to see if it already contains something. If it does, then it appends the new comment to it, else it just assigns the new comment to it. It also makes sure that the the new comment contains something before adding the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.Value` method rather than directly referring to the textboxes.

For that matter, use it whenever referring to an Excel VBA object - checkboxes, etc. This will save you a lot of frustration later with issues like this.

```
Private Sub cmdAddNote_Click()
 Dim MyDate As String

 MyDate = Now()

 Form_ClientF.txtNotes.value = vbCrLf + MyDate + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Form_ClientF.txtAddNote.value + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Form_ClientF.txtNotes.value

 Form_ClientF.txtAddNote.value = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you will make sure you don't run `cmdAddNote_Click` unless `txtAddNote` contains something to add (see example code below).

If that is true, you can do this ...

```vb
Form_ClientF.txtNotes = vbCrLf & MyDate & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
Form_ClientF.txtAddNote & (vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Form_ClientF.txtNotes)
```

This approach takes advantage of the difference between `+` and `&` when used to concatenate a string with Null.  Here is an example from the Immediate window illustrating the difference.

```vb
? "a" + Null
Null
? "a" & Null
a
```

Here is a screen capture of a form which uses this approach ...

[image]

And the code used by the form ...

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdAddNote_Click()
    Me.txtnotes = Format(Now, "mmm dd, yyyy h:nn:ss ampm") & vbCrLf & _
        Me.txtAddNote & (vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Me.txtnotes)
    Me.txtAddNote = vbNullString
    Me.txtAddNote.SetFocus
    Me.cmdAddNote.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.cmdAddNote.Enabled = (Len(Trim(Nz(Me.txtAddNote, vbNullString))) > 0)
End Sub

Private Sub txtAddNote_Change()
    Me.cmdAddNote.Enabled = (Len(Trim(Nz(Me.txtAddNote.Text, vbNullString))) > 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Aha. `&` and `+` behave differently when a `Null` value is involved. Good to know! +1

Answer (score 1):

Contatenating a `Null` value and a string could very well make the whole thing `Null`, so try this instead:

```
Form_ClientF.txtNotes = vbCrLf + MyDate + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Nz(Form_ClientF.txtAddNote, "") + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + Nz(Form_ClientF.txtNotes, "")
```